# how can you change the value of an array in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

how can you change the value of an array 'reactively' by using Vue.js

```
data:{
cafe:[
{dish:’chips’},
{dish:’smokies’},
{dish:’hotdogs’},
(juice:’mango’)
]
}
```

suppose you want to change "chips" to "fish"

Comment: Then you can do `this.cafe[0].dish = 'fish';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$set` for setting value.

```
this.$set(this.cafe[0],'dish','fish');
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/GRJpvZp

Answer (score 0):

You could change your data structure a little bit, to make it more accessable.

```
data:{
  cafe: {
    dish: ["chips", "smokies", "hotdogs"],
    juice: ["mango"]
  }
 }
```

Then, you can filter a little bit easier.

```
this.cafe.dish = [...this.cafe.dish.filter(value => value !== "chips"), "fish"]
```

The dish array get's filtered and returns all values except chips, then you create a new array from the filter return and put in the fish.